# show or detach certain divs on page load

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html

I have two `H1` tags and depending on if the first one has content in it or not, the second one is either visible, or completely removed from the `DOM` until page reload.

1. Attach both `H1` tags.
2. See if `.content-title` actually has any content. If true, remove `visually-hidden`, if false, remove `.content-title`.
3. Start from scratch on page load.

jQuery:

```
// H1 tag checker //
function checkTag() {
    if ($('.content-title').html() != '') {
        $('.visually-hidden').detach();
    } else {
        $('.content-title').detach();
    }
}

$(document).on('load', function () {
    $('.visually-hidden').attach();
    $('.content-title').attach();
    checkTag();
});
```

HTML/C#:

```
<h1 class="content-title">@Html.Raw(content.GetTitle())</h1>
@if (ViewBag.Content.EntityName != "JobPost")
{
    <h1 class="visually-hidden">@ViewBag.Content.Byline</h1>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.attach()` is not a jQuery function.  And `.detach()` is used when you possibly want to add it back again.  You probably just want `.remove()`.  I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish with `.attach()`.

Are you trying to hide and show the elements?  If so, change to `.hide()` and `.show()`:

```
function checkTag() {
    if ($('.content-title').html() != '') {
        $('.visually-hidden').hide();
    } else {
        $('.content-title').hide();
    }
}

$(document).on('load', function () {
    $('.visually-hidden').show();
    $('.content-title').show();
    checkTag();
});
```